# ImportError: cannot import name CvBridge

Tags: python, cv-bridge, opencv2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use the cv_bridge package to convert an Image topic to opencv format on Indigo.  I am using the code from the cv_bridge tutorial, and I added cv_bridge to my package manifest as a build_depend, buildtool_depend, and a run_depend.  When I attempt to run the bridge, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cv_bridge.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
      File    "/home/kghite/catkin_ws/src/comprobo2014/src/neato_robot/neato_2dnav/scripts/cv_bridge.py", line 9, in        <module>
    from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
ImportError: cannot import name CvBridge
```

I would really appreciate any help you can give.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206790/importerror:-cannot-import-name-cvbridge/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-22**:
Hi, I'm having the same issue. Did you solve this by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved quite a while back, but hadn't seen the comment above, so:

It actually ended up being that I had named the python script I was writing cv_bridge.py as well, which was messing with the import statement (basically it was trying to import from itself).  I changed the name and everything worked fine!

---

Originally posted by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) with karma: 92 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0